# How can I programatically obtain the content size of a web page using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

I am looking to scrape the web pages of several golfers on wikipedia. Some of the player names are identical to other people and, in that case, the URL has to have the text '(golfer)' appended to reach the right page

I am looking to try every player with this addition and if the page does not exist then revert to the plain name
There may be a better approach, but I had hoped that I could obtain the content size of the response. If it did not reach a certain level e.g. 2kb then that was not a valid page

```
library(httr)

base_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

query_params <- list(action = "parse", 
  page = "Patrick Reed_(golfer)",
  format = "xml")

resp <- GET(url = base_url, query = query_params)

resp

Response [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? 
action=parse&page=Patrick%20Reed_%28golfer%29&format=xml]
  Date: 2018-04-08 08:35
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
  Size: 402 B
```

So a suitably low size gets reported but I am not sure how to get to it when I expand the list, resp. According to [httr quickstart](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) there is something in the headers referencing content-length but I am unable to discover it

TIA

Comment: Not s direct answer to your question, but why not start scraping recursively from one of the list pages? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_golfers

Comment: And about the content length- it can be referenced by `resp$headers$content-length`

Comment: @R.S. Thanks for that. I did not realize that other page existed. That might be a better approach. Funnily, I still cannot view  the 'content-length` in the RStudio viewer amongst the 23 elements of the headers list

Comment: Unfortunately, the wiki list of golfers includes special characters e.g the accent over the i of Sergio García which makes it hard to match with an unaccented list. Wikipedia pages are clever enough to adjust for the straight unaccented names and adjust

Comment: Ah. hard luck. But then scraping always results in too much 'manual processing'  work. I usually end up making lookup table for some sort of fuzzy string matching with `adist` . Even after that something is left for manual matching.  I had better luck with `RSelenium` because it was able to follow all sorts of links, but haven't used it in some time.